# Adding extra customize function in Excel Pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Hi Excel Pivot expertise,

I'm new in pivot table and also excel, still in learning stage, but just wonder how advance can pivot table goes.

**My Scenario**

Company need to find different supplier and compare their pricing. So in DATE SHEET, we record down all the supplier and their quotation price, also which supplier are currently use by the company.

**My Idea Excel Sheet Function**

Categories the item, list all the supplier and price, then can compare the current item price (current supplier we use) with the cheapest price (Other new supplier quotation we get), then calculate the different percentage

**My difficulties**

I able to create the pivot table, but I'm not able to customize the function I mention above into the pivot table.

**Here's my Data Sheet**

[image]

**This is the simple pivot table I create from the data Sheet**
[image]

**So my question is, can pivot table able to customize this outcome?**
[image]

Or any similar suggestion (using pivot or just normal excel sheet) can achieve my idea outcome?

Thanks in advance =)